# MySQL Event For Deleting Old Records throws error #1064

Tags: mysql, events

I am trying to create an event in MySQL (my first time) that will delete all the records in the "reports" table that are older than 3 months.

The event should run every day at 3:00AM. The reports table has the field "created" of type DATETIME.

This is the code I came up with for creating the event:

```
CREATE 
    EVENT `delete_reports`
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 3 DAY_HOUR
    DO BEGIN
        DELETE FROM `reports` WHERE `created` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

But this throws the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

I understand the 1064 error refers to a syntax problem, but I after looking up several different examples I still haven't managed to get this to work.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Comment: Remove the `BEGIN` statement or add and `end` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an `END` and with that you should change the delimiter. Or you omit the `BEGIN`.

So, either like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `delete_reports`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 3 DAY_HOUR
DO BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `reports` WHERE `created` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

or like this:

```
CREATE EVENT `delete_reports`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 3 DAY_HOUR
DO 
    DELETE FROM `reports` WHERE `created` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```